# PHP htmlspecialchars error

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars

why would this

```
$trader_details = array_walk($trader_details, 'htmlspecialchars');
```

give this error?

```
Severity: Warning
Message: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given
```

afaik htmlspecialchars only has optional parameters apart from the input string? this running in codeigniter

thx

Comment: Removed the codeigniter tag since it does not appear to be contributing to the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback function passed to `array_walk` expects the second parameter to be the key of the array element:

> Typically, *funcname* takes on two parameters. The *array* parameter's value being the first, and the key/index second.

But [`htmlspecialchars`](http://docs.php.net/htmlspecialchars) expects the second parameter to be the quoting style (typically specified by one of the [`ENT_*` constants](http://docs.php.net/htmlentities) of the type integer).

Try [`array_map`](http://docs.php.net/array_map) instead. It just uses the array’s values.

Comment: Severity: Warning

Message: array_map() [function.array-map]: The first argument, 'Array', should be either NULL or a valid callback

Comment: @stef : take a look at the manual : array_map wants parameters in another order than array_walk (yeah... that's one not so nice thing with PHP ^^ ) ; see http://php.net/array_walk and http://php.net/array_map : array_map expects callback first, and array second

Answer (score 2):

array_walk passes 2 arguments by default. The first is the array item value, the second is the array item key. It's trying to pass the array key as the second argument to htmlspecialchars which expects the second argument to be an integer defining the quoting style to use.

Answer (score 1):

http://uk.php.net/array_walk says:

> funcname
>
>     Typically, funcname takes on two parameters. The array parameter's value being the first, and **the key/index second**.

You're probably looking for [aray_map](http://php.net/array_map).
Also note that htmlspecialchars() uses iso-8859-1 as encoding by default. If your output is e.g. utf-8 encoded you have to pass that information as third parameter to htmlspecialchars. Otherwise the result may be wrong.
php 5.3:

```
$foo = array_map(
  function($x) { return htmlspecialchars($x, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8'); },
  $trader_details
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume $trader_details is an array of strings? [htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars)()'s second parameter is an integer type, for the specific quotestyle to be used.

You probably want to use [array_map](https://www.php.net/array_map). If $trader_details is a two-dimensional array, please post it so we can see what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

array_walk passes 2 arguments to your method (htmlspecialchars), first is value of the current array element, second is the *key* of the current element.

so, if

```
$trader_details = array('key' => 'value');
```

then

```
$trader_details = array_walk($trader_details, 'htmlspecialchars');
```

calls

```
htmlspecialchars('value', 'key')
```

And that is incorrect, htmlspecialchars requires the second parameter to be an integer - int $quote_style

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it would do what you want, even if it worked.

The htmlspecialchars() function does not modify the string, it just returns a new string with the modifications. The array walk would not have any affect.

Answer (score -2):

The error is obvious... array_walk's second argument is about function call back, and function needs to have 2 parameters. first one for value and second for key..

Comment: It's not obvious how to send multiple parameters to a function using array_walk.  The OP is not the first to run into this problem.