# PHP: how to perform htmlspecialchar() on an array-of-arrays?

Tags: php, html, arrays, web-applications

How do I run the PHP function `htmlspecialchars()` on an array of array objects?

I have the following code:

```
$result_set = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [home_id] => 1
            [address] => 4225 Nasmyth Dr
            [city] => Plano
            [state] => TX
            [zip] => 76798
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [home_id] => 8
            [address] => 4229 Nasmyth Dr
            [city] => Plano
            [state] => TX
            [zip] => 75093
        )
);

// this doesn't work since $result_set is an array of arrays and htmlspecialchars is expecting a string
htmlspecialchars($result_set, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
```

---

**UPDATE**:

Please note that even though there are quite a few answers below, none of them work for an array-of-arrays. The answers below only work for simple arrays.

I've tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
array_walk_recursive($result_set, "htmlspecialchars", array(ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'))
```

I get the following error: `htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given`

---

**UPDATE 2**

When I try:

```
function cleanOutput(&$value) {
    return htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}
print_r($result_set);
print('-------');
print_r(array_walk_recursive($result_set, "cleanOutput"));
```

I get the following, undesired, output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [home_id] => 1
            [address] => 4225 Nasmyth Dr
            [city] => Plano
            [state] => TX
            [zip] => 76798
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [home_id] => 8
            [address] => 4229 Nasmyth Dr
            [city] => Plano
            [state] => TX
            [zip] => 75093
        )
)
-------1
```

---

**UPDATE 3**

When I try:

```
function cleanOutput(&$value) {
    return htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}
$result_set = Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [home_id] => 1
                [address] => 4225 Nasmyth Dr
                [city] => Plano
                [state] => TX
                [zip] => 76798
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [home_id] => 8
                [address] => 4229 Nasmyth Dr
                [city] => Plano
                [state] => TX
                [zip] => 75093
            )
    );

$cleanedOutput = array();
foreach ($result_set as $rs) {
    $cleaned[] = array_map("cleanOutput", $rs);
}
print_r($cleanedOutput);
```

I get the following, undesired, results:

```
{'homes' : []}
```

Comment: What does `$result_set` contain?

Comment: $result_set is an array from the database of the results I queried for

Comment: What happened when you did a array_map('htmlspecialchars', $result_set, array(ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')) ?  Is the error with htmlspecialchars or array_map?

Comment: What does one of the elements of $result_set look like? All solutions provided thus far assume $result_set is an array of strings. Given the second line of your script, I'm guessing $result_set is an array of hashes.

Comment: @bish, I've updated the original post

Comment: @tvanover, I've updated the original post with the information

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
function filter(&$value) {
  $value = htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}
array_walk_recursive($result_set, "filter");
print_r($result_set);
```

Comment: Shouldn't this work --->  array_walk_recursive("htmlspecialchars", $result_set, array(ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8')) ... but it doesn't. I get the error: "Only variables can be passed by reference"

Comment: Looks like I have the ordering wrong on my parameters. It should be:  array_walk_recursive("htmlspecialchars", $result_set, array(ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'))  ... but now I get a new error: "htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given"

Comment: You still have the order wrong. I updated my example to include the additional arguments that you wanted.

Also, you need to define your own function, as I do above, rather than just passing "htmlspecialchars". This is because array_walk_recursive doesn't normally modify the array itself; it just calls the function on each element. So if you want the function to change the array, you need to make its first argument a reference, as in my &$value above.

Comment: @JW, I've tried the following, but it doesn't work:

array_walk_recursive($result_set, "htmlspecialchars", array(ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'))
I get the following error: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given

Comment: Try the code as I wrote it first. You're misunderstanding the way the third argument to array_walk_recursive works. Check the manual page here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php

Comment: @JW, when I try your code above - it returns an empty array. Even when I change you code from: $value = htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); to return htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ... it still doesn't work

Comment: It's not returning anything -- it's modifying $result_set in-place. Do print_r($result_set) after you run my code, and you'll see the results.

Comment: @JW, see UPDATE 2 for the full results in the original post.

Comment: @JW, as you can see in UPDATE 2 - strange why it isn't working. You can see the output in the original post.

Comment: In UPDATE 2, you're still printing the return value of array_walk_recursive, which is not what you want. Just print $result_set. Slow down a second and read the manual page for array_walk_recursive ... you'll see how it works. I modified my example above to print the array.

Comment: Thank You @JW. Code works perfect. Could you please briefly explain why we are using `&` symbol inside `filter(&$value)` with `$value`?

Comment: REAL PERFECT ANSWER

Answer (score 28):

You can use [`array_map()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to run that method on each entry.

```
$cleaned = array_map("htmlspecialchars", $myArray);
```

If you need to pass arguments to `htmlspecialchars()`, you can substitute it for your own custom function:

```
function myFunc($a) {
  return htmlspecialchars($a, ENT_QUOES);
}

$cleaned = array_map("myFunc", $myArray);
```

Considering the fact that you're dealing with an array of arrays, and not an array of strings, you would need to cycle through the outer-array to get to your strings:

```
$cleaned = array();
foreach ($result_set as $rs) {
  foreach ($rs as $r) {
    $cleaned[] = array_map("htmlspecialchars", $r);
  }
}
```

Or, you could use `array_walk_recursive()`:

```
array_walk_recursive($myArray, "htmlspecialchars");
```

Note that this method changes the $myArray object by reference, so there's no need to assign the output to a new variable.

Comment: How do I use array_map() if I want to pass agruments to htmlspecialchars?  Meaning, how do I pass the arguements of ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'" to htmlspecialchars?

Comment: Meaning, 'array_map("htmlspecialchars", $result_set)' does not allows me to pass in the argument of ENT_QUOTES and UTF-8

Comment: TeddyR, make your own function that calls htmlspecialchars with those arguments, and call your function instead.

Comment: Why wouldn't this work -->  array_map('htmlspecialchars', $result_set, array(ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'))   ???

Comment: I receive the following error, "htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given" when using rray_map('htmlspecialchars', $result_set, array(ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'))

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson, why do I need to create another function (myFunc)?

Comment: The arrays passed to array_map should be of equal length. The argument list for the callback function is comprised of one element from each array. If you wanted to do it this way, the call to array_map would look like this: array_map('htmlspecialchars', $result_set, array_fill(0, count($result_set), ENT_QUOTES), array_fill(0, count($result_set), 'UTF-8')). Take Jonathan's advice. It's much simpler and cleaner.

Comment: You could also use an anonymous function (PHP 5.3 and later) that calls `htmlspecialchars` with the appropriate arguments:
http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: @bish, I receive an error when trying your way. The error is: "array_fill() [<a href='function.array-fill'>function.array-fill</a>]: Number of elements must be positive in"

Comment: @TeddyR Make sure count($result_set) is actually returning the length of the $result_set array. If it's returning 0, that will cause the error you're seeing.

Comment: @Jonathan, when I try your way - I receive the following error: "htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string"

Comment: @TeddyR, your first-level types are arrays. $result_set[0] is an array, not a string. Within your clean-method you need to address the strings, not arrays.

Comment: @Jonathan, so how would I do this then given that I have an array of arrays

Comment: @TeddyR, you could use `foreach`.

Comment: @Jonathan, thanks for the update ... just one last question. What's the most efficient way if I also wanted to pass the ENT_QUOTES and 'UTF-8' agruments to the htmlspecialchars() function using an array-of-arrays?

Comment: when I try: array_walk_recursive("htmlspecialchars", $result_set, array(ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'))  .... I get the following error: "Only variables can be passed by reference"

Comment: Your array is the first argument in `array_walk_recursive`, not the second.

Comment: When I update my code to: array_walk_recursive($result_set, "htmlspecialchars", array(ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'))  ... , I get a new error: "htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 2 to be long, string"

Comment: @Jonathan, any ideas? You've been of huge help so far.

Comment: @TeddyR, if you wish to use additional arguments, it appears you should go with my earlier suggestion, `foreach` and `array_map` according to the consensus on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317063/php-htmlspecialchars-error

Comment: @Jonathan, using the foreach doesn't work. See my UPDATE 3 to my original post.

Comment: @TeddyR, oh, I think you'll need a nested-foreach. See my updated foreach.

Answer (score 6):

A lot of the answers on this page are either insufficient, outdated, or use the wrong parameters for [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) or [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php). Here's a function that will fix all scalar values in an array recursively.

#### htmlspecialchars_recursive()

```
<?php

function htmlspecialchars_recursive ($input, $flags = ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401, $encoding = 'UTF-8', $double_encode = false) {
    static $flags, $encoding, $double_encode;
    if (is_array($input)) {
        return array_map('htmlspecialchars_recursive', $input);
    }
    else if (is_scalar($input)) {
        return htmlspecialchars($input, $flags, $encoding, $double_encode);
    }
    else {
        return $input;
    }
}

$test = array(
    0 => array(
        'test-1' => 'testing <p>html tag</p> will be fixed',
        'test-2' => '&reg; valid and will be left intact',
        'test-3' =>  '© 2080 kept intact'
    ),
    1 => array(
        'test-4' => array(
            'test-5' => 'deeper fix on <p>html tag</p> test',
            'test-6' => '&reg; will be left intact',
            'test-7' =>  '© 2080 kept intact'
        )
    )
);

print_r(htmlspecialchars_recursive($test));

?>
```

#### Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [test-1] => testing &lt;p&gt;html tag&lt;/p&gt; will be fixed
            [test-2] => &reg; valid and will be left intact
            [test-3] => © 2080 kept intact
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [test-4] => Array
                (
                    [test-5] => deeper fix on &lt;p&gt;html tag&lt;/p&gt; test
                    [test-6] => &reg; will be left intact
                    [test-7] => © 2080 kept intact
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 4):

You may wish to use array_map as Jonathon Sampson suggested, another alternative is [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)

The difference is that array_map returns a copy of the array with the function applied to each element, while array_walk operates directly on the array you supply.

Answer (score 4):

Made way to make it work for multi-dimensional arrays:

```
function secure($val) {
    return (is_array($val))?array_map('secure',$val):htmlspecialchars($val, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}
```

It works, that it calls its-self on array without last used array and if its not an array, it passes it to htmlspecialchars function.

Input: `Array ( [0] => test< [1] => Array ( [test>] => <test?> ) [2] => Array ( [0] => test [1] => > [2] => Array ( [0] => bigtest<> ) ) )`

Output: `Array ( [0] => test&lt; [1] => Array ( [test>] => &lt;test?&gt; ) [2] => Array ( [0] => test [1] => &gt; [2] => Array ( [0] => bigtest&lt;&gt; ) ) )`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create your own function if you are passing multiple arguments to the called back function.

According to [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

`array array_map  ( callback $callback  , array $arr1  [, array $...  ] )`

So that means if you want to pass multiple arguments you should just pass:

```
$clean_array = array_map("htmlspecialchars", $myArray, array(ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
```

but for some reason this doesn't work for me.

But this seems to does, don't ask me why.

```
$clean_array = array_map("htmlspecialchars", $myArray, array(ENT_QUOTES), array('UTF-8'));
```

Comment: This does not work. I receive the error:  array_map() [<a href='function.array-map'>function.array-map</a>]: Argument #3 should be an array

Comment: So, I'm stumped. Because neither your way nor Jonathan's way works. Both generate errors, see my comments for the exact errors.

Comment: I have revised it, it seems to work for me, but test it and see if it outputs properly for you.  For some reason if I put both arguments in the same array it stated that "htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 2 to be long".  You got me.

Comment: @travover, In your second example, I receive the following error: "htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given"

Comment: @tvanover This would only work for the first element of the array. Look at Example #3 in the documentation and the comment immediately after it as to why.

Comment: Well nuts,  Looks like the custom function is the one.  Or do the array_fill.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use array_map and pass the function arguments, you can create your own function and use that as the callback:

```
 function cleanhtml($dirtyhtml) {
       return htmlspecialchars($dirtyhtml, UTF-8);
  }

  $cleaned = array_map("cleanhtml", $myArray);
```

Comment: you don't really need your own function, array_map can pass multiple arguments to the target callback function.  array array_map  ( callback $callback  , array $arr1  [, array $...  ] )  The only time you would want to create your own is if you are doing more than one thing to every object in the array.

Comment: I noticed that from the comment above. But the php documentation does NOT make it very clear. One simple example would really be helpful. All of their examples assume user-written functions.

Comment: This generates the following error: "htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string" when I use the following code: function cleanhtml($dirtyhtml) {
       return htmlspecialchars($dirtyhtml, ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');
  }

  $cleaned = array_map("cleanhtml", $myArray);

Answer (score 0):

```
function htmlspecialchars_array_modify (&$arr){
        array_walk_recursive($arr,function(&$value){
            $value=htmlspecialchars($value);
        });
        return $arr;
    }
```

// this will alter the source

Answer (score 0):

**Validation Class function**

```
function htmlspecialchars_recursive ($input, $flags = ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401, $encoding = 'UTF-8', $double_encode = false) {
    static $flags, $encoding, $double_encode;
    if (is_array($input)) {
        return array_map(array($this, 'htmlspecialchars_recursive'), $input);
    }
    else if (is_scalar($input)) {
        return htmlspecialchars($input, $flags, $encoding, $double_encode);
    }
    else {
        return $input;
    }
}
```

**Details:**

> $input = your input  **array() or scalar types like  integer, float, string or boolean.**
>
> $flags = [PHP Available flags constant description here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)
>
> $encoding = encoding type **default: UTF-8**
>
> $double_encode  = based on your needs, you can used. **TURE or FALSE**

**Function call**

```
 //It will convert htmlentities
$param =  $this->htmlspecialchars_recursive($_REQUEST);
// print_r($param);
```

**Output:**

```
/*
        array(
            [whyiitgnq] => &lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;b&gt;teste&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;b&gt;tetst&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ul&gt;&lt;div&gt;&lt;i&gt;&lt;u&gt;tets&lt;/u&gt;&lt;/i&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;tets&lt;/div&gt;&lt;ol&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;b&gt;tetst&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;b&gt;tetst&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;b&gt;test&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ol&gt;
            [_wysihtml5_mode] => 1
            [aid] => 12695
        )
        */
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another generic version that uses array_walk and behaves in the way that htmlspecialchars does with respect to parameters.

```
function htmlspecialchars_r($string, 
    int $flags = ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401, 
    string $encoding = null,
    bool $double_encode = true )
{
    if ($encoding === null)
    {
        $encoding =  ini_get("default_charset");
    }

    $filter = function(&$value, $flags, $params) {
        $value = htmlspecialchars($value, $params['flags'], $params['encoding'], $params['double_encode']);
    };

    array_walk_recursive($string, $filter,
        array(
            'flags' => $flags,
            'encoding' => $encoding,
            'double_encode' => $double_encode,
        )
    );

    return $string;
}
```