# Output escaping on arrays to protect against xss

Tags: php, json, jtable, xss, sql-injection

I need to write a report on ways to protect against SQL injection and XSS and what ways the security in a website I created could be improved.

On my website I used jquery's jTable to display data from a MySQL database.

Inputs for new entries into the db are sanitised using mysql_real_escape_string:

```
$fieldName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["fieldName"]);
```

(although in my report I have suggested that using prepared satements is a better option and why)

Outputs are displayed using:

```
print json_encode($jTableResult);
```

When testing my website I realised that although I had made it harder for SQL injection I could still save HTML and javascript code into the db which would then execute when displayed to the browser. As I didnt know how to solve this I just added the strip_tags function on user inputs:

```
$fieldName = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST["fieldName"]));
```

Now that I need to produce this report I want to state the correct way this should have been done and what I could of improved.

So my question... How do you escape outputs in arrays?

Hope this makes sense

Comment: @randomizer I have used htmlspecialchars in another part of my site that displays a sent email to the browser so will also be mentioning this at some point in my report however do you know if htmlspecialchars will work to remove tags for data in arrays?

Comment: No, to remove tags you have to use strip_tags, if you want to show the html as is, you can use htmlspecialchars($text) and it will be shown as text and not as html.

Comment: @randomizer sorry I should rephase that... Can you use htmlspecialchars with arrays to show the html,javascript as is? Basically what im wanting to know is, does any command such as this exist (and work): print json_encode(htmlspecialchars($jTableResult)); For using on outputs rather than inputs

Comment: Yes that is possible, not with one simple command, but have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002710/php-how-to-perform-htmlspecialchar-on-an-array-of-arrays

Comment: @randomizer ahh thank you. Just needed to know that it could be done. I can now mention this in my report and give that function as an example. All the resources I have read through advise that its best to use htmlspecialchars when dealing with outputs rather than inputs

Comment: Indeed, you should save html as is and make sure you format it when you want to output it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use htmlspecialchars to output html as plain text:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_htmlspecialchars.asp

strip_tags removes the tags, unless you specify specific tags that can be shown in the output.

Mysql_real_escape_string is used to escape characters for SQL input..
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysql_real_escape_string.asp

However, have a look into Mysqli or PDO and prepared statements to enhance your security.
Mysql is depricated.

Comment: May be so, but the provided links are straight on and usable.

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated as of php 5.5. It'd be better if you linked straight to PHP manual, and/or OWASP security guide. Thanks!

Comment: @Misiur yeah im aware of this but we were told to just use mysql_ Either their using old assignments or they are looking for us to mention something about it in our report which I have already done when suggesting using prepared statements as not available in mysql_*

Comment: Prepared statements are excellent to deal with SQL injection. I updated it in my answer because it could be relevant for your assignment.  You should absolutely mention to your teacher that he/she shouldn't use mysql anymore.  However, we were talking about outputs, thats another issue :)